# Dash Bootstrap components not changing linked url

Tags: python, web-applications, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am working on a Dash app and want to include a button/hyperlink to a local html file, however I need to be able to change the html file depending on what search term is input. Below is what I currently have, but I keep getting an error saying the dbc.Button doesn't support 'n-clicks'. I also had an issue with the link immediately being opened when the script was ran. I've never used the Dash Bootstrap components before so I'm not really sure what I need to do to fix this issue.

*This is just a snippet of the code so that it wasn't too long*

```
    app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('Gene-NE'),
    html.H5('Created by Lauren Kirsch and Dr. Chiquito Crasto'),
    html.Label('Search Box'),
    dcc.Input(id="search_gene",
        type="text",
        value='',
        placeholder="Type a human gene name",
        debounce=True,
        minLength=0, maxLength=50,
        autoComplete='on',
        size='40'),
    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(id='mygraph')]),
    dcc.RadioItems(
        id="vertical_display_toggle",
        options=[
            {'label': 'Show vertical date bars', 'value': 'show'},
            {'label': 'Hide vertical bars', 'value': 'hide'}],
        value='hide',  # first loading value selected
        labelStyle={'display': 'inline-block'}, inputStyle={"margin-left": "8px", "margin-right": "5px"}),
    dcc.RadioItems(
        id="synonym_display_toggle",
        options=[
            {'label': 'Show synonyms', 'value': 'show'},
            {'label': 'Hide synonyms', 'value': 'hide'}],
        value='hide',  # first loading value selected
        labelStyle={'display': 'inline-block'}, inputStyle={"margin-left": "8px", "margin-right": "5px"}),
    html.Div([
        dbc.Button("Click Here", id="id-button", className="mr-2"),
        html.A(dbc.Nav(dbc.NavItem(dbc.NavLink('Click for PubMedIDs', id='outlink', href='/', target="_blank",
            className="nav-link"))))
    ]),
    html.Br(),
    html.H6('Texas Tech University Center for Biotechnology and Genomics')])
    
df = pd.read_csv('list_out.txt', sep='\t', dtype=str)
df = df.transpose().reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'Date'})
new_header = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]
df.columns = new_header
df = df.iloc[0:600]
df = df.set_index('Date')
df = df.iloc[:, ~df.columns.duplicated()]

lookup_df = pd.read_csv('Gene_Lookup.csv', dtype=str)
link = lookup_df.set_index('Approved_Symbol').Linked_Genes.str.split('|').to_dict()
link_date = lookup_df.set_index('Approved_Symbol').Date_Name_Changed.to_dict()   
    
@app.callback(
    [Output('mygraph', 'figure'),
    Output('outlink', 'children')],
    [Input('search_gene', 'value'),
     Input('vertical_display_toggle', 'value'),
     Input('synonym_display_toggle', 'value'),
     Input('id-button', 'n-clicks')])

def update_output(search_gene, vertical_display_user_slct, synonym_display_user_slct, clicks):        
    if search_gene:
        search_gene = search_gene.upper()
        syns = link[search_gene]
                
        
    trace1 = go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df[search_gene], line_shape='linear', line=dict(color='white'), name=search_gene)
        
    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_trace(trace1)
                
    if clicks != 0:
        return 'f"/assets/{search_gene}.html"'
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you've specified `n-clicks` as input and it needs to be `n_clicks` instead.

So for clarity, the callback should look more like this:

```
@app.callback(
    [Output("mygraph", "figure"), Output("outlink", "children")],
    [
        Input("search_gene", "value"),
        Input("vertical_display_toggle", "value"),
        Input("synonym_display_toggle", "value"),
        Input("id-button", "n_clicks"),
    ],
)
def update_output(
    search_gene, vertical_display_user_slct, synonym_display_user_slct, clicks
):
    # ...
```

As far as the link problem goes, I'm not able to reproduce this with what you've shared, but in your callback you have this check:

```
if clicks != 0:
    return 'f"/assets/{search_gene}.html"'
```

`clicks` can also be `None` so make sure this gets handled correctly. Instead you could do something this:

```
if clicks:
    return 'f"/assets/{search_gene}.html"'
```

This will handle `None` as well.